# Comparing the data from one file to another and print the output

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have three files of name -  File1, File2 and File3. The data of the three files is shown below:

File1:

```
    // Class of "A2" of type "ONE".
    // Class of "A3" of type "ONE".
    // Class of "D1" of type "TWO".
    // Class of "D2" of type "TWO".
    // Class of "D3" of type "FOUR".
    // Class of "D6" of type "FIVE."
```

File2:

```
@CLASS_NAMES = ("one",
    "two",
    "three",);
@CLASS_LIST_NAMES = ("ONE.A1",
    "ONE.A2",
    "ONE.A3",
    "TWO.D1",
    "TWO.D2");
```

File3:

```
D3
D4
D5
```

I need to check in **File1** Class "**D3**" is present in the **File2** of **@CLASS_LIST_NAMES** or not.
If it is not present in **File2** of **@CLASS_LIST_NAMES** then I need to check in **File3** if **D3** is present there or not.
If **D3** is present in **File3** then the output should be as **PASS** and if it not present in both File2 and File3 the output should be **FAIL**.

Similarly I need to check for all the Class list-(A2, A3, D1, D2....) from **File1** if they are present in the File2 of **@CLASS_LIST_NAMES** or not and if they are not present in File2, I need to verify with File3 and print the output as PASS or FAIL.

I tried the below code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -n '/@CLASS_LIST_NAMES =/,/)/p' File2
```

I'm stuck at here, can anyone tell me what need to be done next.

**Deisred_Output**: As from **File1** - **D6** is not found in both File2 and File3 it should print as **FAIL**. The output should be like below:

```
Fail: D6 is not found
```

Comment: You can accomplish this by using a combination of `IF/ELSE` and `grep` ...

Comment: can you add a sample for desired output?

Comment: @AhmetSaidAkbulut I modified the question. Please find my desired output. As from File1 -  D6 is not present in both the File2 and File3, the output should be as **Fail** on **D6** .

Comment: @ADAPANIKHIL : Step 1: Put all class names from File 1 into an array. Step 2: Put all class names from File 2 into an array. Step 3: Put all class names from File 3 into an array. Step 4: Process the arrays to implement your algorithm. Since you are going to process more than one class, it will likely be more efficient to have all data in memory, instead of traversing the same file again and again.

Comment: @user1934428 But how to process the File1 and File2 data into an array. The data will be changing randomly so...

Comment: If the data is changing **while your script is running**, you have a race condition, and this is then a different problem, which you would need to address in a separate question. In a realistic situation, the script is supposed to run within a fraction of seconds, and if you don't want to have the files being secretly modified, you need to do some locking anyway.

Comment: @user1934428 The data will not change when the script is running. But the above given inputs are just a example of few. There will be lots of Class in File1 and **CLASS_LIST_NAMES** in File2 , so the data will be changing in File1 and File2. So we need to compare the **Class** in **File1** to **CLASS_LIST_NAMES** in File2.

Comment: The question is for bash, but perhaps this is better handled in a more capable language like Python, Perl or similar ?

Comment: @ADAPANIKHIL : So, why does this contradict my suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with `grep` and `awk`

Use GNU grep which supports `-P` option

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a){print "Fail: "$0 " is not found"}' <(cat file3 <(grep -Po '(?<=\.)[^"]+' file2)) <(grep -Po '(?<=of ")\w+' file1)
```

If you want to extract the classnames present only in the `@CLASS_LIST_NAMES` statement use below one.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a){print "Fail: "$0 " is not found"}' <(cat file3 <(sed -n '/@CLASS_LIST_NAMES/,/;$/p' | grep -Po '(?<=\.)[^"]+' file2)) <(grep -Po '(?<=of ")\w+' file1)
```

If the no of spaces in the file1 are not consistent, you can process using `awk`

```
# expects the 4th column is the variable, input format shouldn't change

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {gsub("\"","",$4)} !($4 in a){print "Fail: "$4" is not found"}' <(cat file3 <(sed -n '/@CLASS_LIST_NAMES/,/;$/p' | grep -Po '(?<=\.)[^"]+' file2)) file1
```

```
# alternate way using FPAT if the position of actual field can change, but it occurs first between double quotes

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {gsub("\"","",$1)} !($1 in a){print "Fail: "$1" is not found"}' <(cat file3 <(sed -n '/@CLASS_LIST_NAMES/,/;$/p' | grep -Po '(?<=\.)[^"]+' file2)) FPAT="\"[^ \"]+" file1
```

Comment: Can you please explain me the code. What we are doing in the code...

Comment: The code is working fine for the given samples, can you please explain me the code, how you are processing only the data in File2, because in File2 we need to check only in **CLASS_LIST_NAMES** ..

Comment: @ADAPANIKHIL I'm extracting the part after `.` in the file2, which is the classname. `"ONE.A2"` gets converted to `A2` by using  `grep`

Comment: Is there a way to extract  **.** only for **CLASS_LIST_NAME** . The extraction operation should be performed between starting string as **@CLASS_LIST_NAMES = (** and ending string as **)** .

Comment: Please update the inputs in the question. Currently the class names are part of `@CLASS_LIST_NAMES` itself. Be more detailed in terms of what is the exact input and output.

Comment: `sed -n '/@CLASS_LIST_NAMES/,/;$/p' file2` this will give you the lines which correspond to `@CLASS_LIST_NAMES`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234612/discussion-between-adapa-nikhil-and-barathvutukuri).